# Is it possible to get the "global" index from NSIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I have different sections on my `UITableView` property `NSIndexPath.row` will give me the index within current section.

Is it possible to get the absolute index of the cell in the table without taking into account sections?

For example: if a table has 2 sections with the first having with 10 items, I want to get index = 10 for the first element of the second section.

Comment: Why do you need a global index? It doesn't make sense. If you really need it, what you can do is add up all your sections and create a Global index path of your own maintain it your self.

Comment: @Harsh: I need it because I use it to detect when to get more items for a infinite scroll

Comment: override `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` in your delegate and then you can detect when user reach to end of tableview

Comment: If you just want to see whether you reach the end of scroll, override the scroll view delegates and find it out. I can answer with one example

Comment: @Harsh: thanks for your answer but I want to trigger data loading for infinite scroll before reaching the end. I will analyze if using scroll position detection is a better approach.

Comment: Cool.. Globel index would not be the approach to implement infinite scroll. There are lots of other ways to do it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with some of the comments that this might not be the best way to implement infinite scrolling. Answering your original question though, you could do something like this in Swift:

```
extension UITableView {
    func globalIndexPath(for localIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
        var totalRows = 0
        for i in 0..<localIndexPath.section {
            totalRows += self.numberOfRowsInSection(i)
        }
        return totalRows + localIndexPath.row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether you have reached the end of the table view you can do it with the following code:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
    let bounds = scrollView.bounds
    let size = scrollView.contentSize
    let inset = scrollView.contentInset
    let y = CGFloat(offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom)
    let h = CGFloat(size.height)

    let reload_distance = CGFloat(-100)

    if (y > (h + reload_distance)) {
        //Do something heree... The code will reach here once the table view reaches the end. 
    }
}
```